# Cannot see /etc/shadow in augeas

Tags: augeas

I am kind of new to Augeas and am trying to get a handle on it. i was hoping to manipulate local accounts using augeas but cannot parse the /etc/shadow file.

I am using Augeas version 1.0.0 on CentOS 6. I see there are newer versions but cannot make too many changes to this system.

My distribution does not come with a lense for /etc/shadow so I thought I could just use the one from the newer version so I copied shadow.aug to /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist.

augparse seems to work:

```
[x dist]$ augparse shadow.aug
[x dist]$
```

When I look for shadow in augtool it is not there

```
augtool> ls /files/etc/shadow
augtool> print /files/etc/shadow
augtool>
```

I even tried changing the access rights on shadow

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you launching `augtool` as root? `/etc/shadow` is (hopefully) not readable by anyone else...

Comment: I just tried it as root and it doesn't see it either. FYI, I am working in the sandbox that they suggest in the Augeas Quick Tour so the files are all owned by me. But I did change the access rights on shadow as I mentioned above, to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Is the lens in the standard lens location?

Comment: It is here:  /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist As far as i know this is the standard location.

Comment: What does `print /augeas//error` say in `augtool`. Does it give a hint about a parse error for this file?

Comment: I am not sure. There is 60 lines or so of output with no time stamps on them. I can't tell if they are old errors from work I did yesterday or they are caused when I do ls /files/etc/shadow. Only two lines reference shadow. Is there a way to clear this error log so I can try again?

Comment: This is not an error log, it's just parsing errors when you start Augeas (Augeas is not a service, just a parsing library).